# Cannot find symbol on method

Tags: java, methods, cannot-find-symbol

i'm creating the method toArray in the code below, getting cannot find symbol error in calling both pop() and push() methods inside toArray. Why?

```
   public void push(Comparable x)
   {
      arr[size++] = x;
   }

   public Object pop() throws EmptyStackException
   {
      return arr[size--];
   }

   public Comparable[] toArray() 
   {
      Comparable[] newarr = new Comparable[size];
      for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
         newarr[i] = arr.pop();
      }
      for(int i = size; i > 0; i--)
      {
         arr.push(newarr[i-1]);
      }
      return newarr;
   }
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error, preferably a stacktrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `arr.push()` and `arr.pop()`. However the push and pop are methods in your class. Just call `push(arr);` and `pop` without the arr prefix.

Comment: Is it correct to think that those methods already refers to "this" and so arr. is incorrect?

Comment: Correct. Because you are in the context of your Class, just calling `push()` is equivalent to calling `this.push()`. Trying to invoke `arr.push()` would mean you are attempting to call a method on `arr`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your other uses of `arr`, it looks like it has been defined as an array of objects. Java arrays by themselves do not have access to push and pop methods.

If you're looking to access the `push` and `pop` methods you've created, use

```
pop();
push(newarr[i-1]);
```

Rather than:

```
arr.pop();
arr.push(newarr[i-1]);
```